# JQuery "load" worked in Bracket's Live Preview, but not when uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modx

I am working on a website in which I want to load web pages through Jquery's .load function as a part of an overlay type of navigation. I use Brackets to code and its Live Preview function has proven to be very useful.

While developing I already noticed that the load function only worked in the Live Preview mode, and not if I open the page in a regular browser window, so I assumed that Live Preview emulates a server in some way and that's why it worked.

However, when I uploaded my files to the server through the MODx content management system that I use, the function seems to have stopped working.

For the sake of completion, here's the code snippet that I use:

> {$( ".div" ).load( "page.html" );

Can anybody tell me why this is happening? I've read some stuff about security protocol issues with .load, but since all files are on the same server I don't think that's the issue. Don't take my word for it, though. I'm a designer first and a developer... third or fourth, probably.

EDIT: The console gives me a 404 error.

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Kind regards

Comment: Have you looked at your network console to see the request being made, and what response code it gets (200, 304, 404, etc)?

Comment: You need to press F12 in the browser and see what the console says, if there are any errors and then add the errors you get to the question with the code it came from. I guess you forgot to upload `page.html` or you uploaded in the wrong location.

Comment: I get a 404 error, which is odd since the link seems to be valid.

Comment: Is that the entire code snippet? The unclosed curly bracket is making me twitchy...